# In JAXB, Why does some elements generate with the Long datatype, and others with the long datatype when minOccurs is defined?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I found something pretty peculiar, and probably insignificant. When you define in an XSD an Element with the type `xs:long`, and you don't set `minOccurs="0"`, and you run it through JAXB, the resulting element is of type `long`. However, when you do set `minOccurs="0"` in the XSD element, the resulting element is of type `Long`. Notice the difference between the `long` and `Long` DataType

Now, with the work I do, I do some `if (thisVariable == null)` tests, and naturally, `long` cannot be null. `Long` can.

****What I would like to know, is this a bug in JAXB which causes this difference between the resulting variables, or is it intended for these resulting variables to come out the way they do? ****

Here was the files I used to test with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema id="ReportRequestWrapper" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="ReportRequestWrapper">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="queryId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="reportId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

`queryId` and `reportId` came out as follows:

```
public class ReportRequestWrapper {

    protected Long queryId;
    protected Long reportId;
```

If I omitted the MinOccurs="0",

```
        <xs:element name="queryId" type="xs:long"  />
        <xs:element name="reportId" type="xs:long"  />
```

The result turned into

```
public class ReportRequestWrapper {

    protected long queryId;
    protected long reportId;
```

I just found this pretty curious and wanted some more information on this one.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question as you provide all the answers yourself: if the element in the XSD is marked as optional, the wrapper type is used (null == omit)

Comment: If you leave out the minOccurs="0", then the element is *required* to occur exactly once. So `null` would not be a valid value, so why *should* it be supported? `long` is the correct data type in that case.

Comment: I learned something today :D 

I am still new to JAXB though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not a bug because when you say `minOccurs = "0"` which means that there is a possibility that `queryId` may be present or not.

So as you said `long` cannot be `null`, so the case that it is not present cannot be simulated without `Long`.

And when you don't specify `minOccurs = "0"` this means that **no matter what the value** (other that `null` i.e. not present), `queryId` would be present. So this case is satisfied totally with `long` and does not require `Long`.